# iphone Developing

Tags: objective-c

I have 4 tabs in my application. After launching my application i want to start with landscape. Now i want to restrict one view from landscape, I tried with `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];` now the view is restricting landscape and force the view into portrait then no issue right,now i will go to any other tab which are in my application they should not rotate to landscape mode.

After come back to home view where i was started my application then all are working fine.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following method to your `UIViewController`:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

If you want to allow Landscape:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{ 
     return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

If you want to allow Portrait:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{ 
     return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

If Both:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{ 
     return YES;
}
```